# how can i get Shortest Path cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a Neo4j database with the cypher statement here:https://gist.github.com/neoecos/8748091

i want to know : how to get :
           1.less Transfer Paths (order by transfer)
           2.the Shortest Path （order by path length)
           3.the optimal Path (less Transfer and the Shortest Path)

please give the corresponding query. 
And do you think that is the best way to create a Bus inquiry system？
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortest path is pretty easy:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((station_44:STATION {id:44})-[*0..10]-(station_46:STATION {id:46}))
RETURN path
```

As far as counting transfers you can do something like this:

```
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((station_44:STATION {id:44})-[rels*0..10]-(station_46:STATION {id:46}))
RETURN length(path) AS stop_count, length(FILTER(index IN RANGE(1, length(rels)-1) WHERE (rels[index]).bus <> (rels[index - 1]).bus)) AS transfer_count
```

Once you have those two variables you can calculate / sort however you like.  For example:

```
MATCH path=(station_44:STATION {id:44})-[rels*0..4]-(station_46:STATION {id:46})
WITH length(path) AS stop_count, length(FILTER(index IN RANGE(1, length(rels)-1) WHERE (rels[index]).bus <> (rels[index - 1]).bus)) AS transfer_count
RETURN stop_count, transfer_count
ORDER BY (stop_count * 0.5) + (transfer_count * 2.0) DESC
```

Here I removed the `allShortestPaths` call so that you get different lengths of paths.  The `ORDER BY` uses weights on the two metrics.  Unfortunately, at least in my DB, if you go beyond a path length of four it starts to get really slow.  You might be able to improve that by introducing a direction arrow in the path, if that makes sense in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i know to shortest path is pretty easy.  i want to get less Transfer Paths and the optimal Path.   i  do not get any process yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The length/filter bit should figure out the number of transfers for your path.

Comment: i think your suggestion is very helpful , i just make it order by "transfer_count" , then i get what i want.  thanks

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear it!

Comment: furthermore how can i get the path order by relationship property , for example order by bus.name ?

Comment: The path will have (potentially) multiple relationships, so you might want to order on the array of those bus names.  So you might put this in your `WITH`: `EXTRACT(rel in rels | rel.bus) AS bus_names` and then `ORDER BY bus_names`